# Understanding rotation matrices derivation

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

Reading a book - "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Directx12 by Frank Luna", I did not understand how we got the rotation matrix from function

[image]

the rotation matrix is:

[image]

to get this matrix from this rule:

[image]

Comment: It's stil not clear after this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation

Answer (score 1):

Very nice formula.

Assuming `|n|=1`, the term `(n.v)n` is the projection of `v` in the direction of `n`, that must be unchanged.

The term `v - (n.v)n` is the projection of `v` in the plane normal to `n`, thus  multiplied by `cos(theta)`.

The term `n x v` is the vector normal to the plane containing `n` and `v`, thus multiplied by `sin(theta)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that cross product and projection can be represented as matrices
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The geometry of rotation about a vector n.
[image]

[image]